# Use fastreport.net without installation

Tags: iis, fastreport

Is there a way to use fastreport.net in shared iis host with out fastreport installation. and using only dlls.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and installed the latest version. Then, i copied these DLLs to my project direcotry and referenced them:

- FastReport.dll

These two, you only need, when you use the "ShowReport" (preview window).

- FastReport.Bars.dll
- FastReport.Editor.dll

When you only want to create reports and save/export them, FastReport.dll would be enough.